# string to date conversion with condition - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, trim

I have a Table with coloumnname `description`

```
   description  //character varying
LZ000834_28-02-14
LZ000834_28-02-14
LA20683_30-04-15
LA20683_30-04-15
LA20300_31-01-15
LA20300_31-01-15
LA20264_31-01-15
LA20264_31-01-15
LAN2078_31-03-15
LAN2078_31-03-15
L2Z82736_31_03_2015 //this is rare case but this kind of dates also possible
```

here description means `batchname_expirydate`

my question is how do I separate `batchname` and `expiry date` and display only the description whose expiration date is `>now+120` days

thanks,

Comment: Why don't you properly normalize your data? Then you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: ok that is secondary.. but how to do for regular description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to normalize your data, add a column to your table which contains the expiry date of each product, add an index to that column and select accordingly.

The quick way is to use a regex

```
with product_dates AS (
    select description, case when val[4]::int > 1900 then 
        (val[4]||'-'||val[3]||'-'||val[2])::date else
        ((val[4]::int+2000)||'-'||val[3]||'-'||val[2])::date end as expir_date
    from ( 
        select description,regexp_matches(description, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([0-9]+)[-_]([0-9]+)[-_]([0-9]+)') as val 
        from your_table_name
    ) a
), expiring_dates AS (
    select description from product_dates where expir_date > now() + '120 days'
)
select description from expiring_dates
```

I'm sure the above can be optimized a bit, but that's not the point, is it? Don't forget to change `your_table_name` with your real table name

Comment: Curious. It works for me with the data in your example. Which version of postgres do you have and what do you get by running just this `select description,regexp_matches(description, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_(\d+)[-_](\d+)[-_](\d+)') as val from your_table_name`?

Comment: postgres v8.4

select description,regexp_matches(description, '([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_(\d+)[-_](\d+)[-_](\d+)') as val 
        from attributesetinstance

ive run only this comand.. i dont get any results

Comment: This means that the regex does not match, which means that the example data you supplied is not exactly like this. Try Filipe's solution instead of my regex (although my regex still works on Filipe's fiddle, his solution is better and more readable)

Comment: aah ok, seems that Postgres 8.4 does not understand `\d` so just use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`. I've editted my answer and this will work as well

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with previous comments that this should be normalized, In order to get the dates from those strings you can try this:

```
select to_date(substring(col1 from position('_' in col1) + 1), 'DD-MM-YY')
from tab1;
```

This will transform the text after the first `_` to a date.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/dd07c/1)</kbd>